# SQL query, multiple JOIN and SELECT (?) statements

Tags: sql, select, join

I've looked through a lot of answers, and tried different options in the code, but I couldn't get the result I need or the query doesn't work at all. So have to ask for help.

*it is a school lab task, but I was sick this week, so missed the opportunity to ask teachers and now deadline for this and more of similar tasks is this weekend, so have to figure it out somehow*

I need to combine three tables. No problem with that, but from the same table (Teacher) I need to get teacher name for each course plus advisor teacher for the course (from Subject).

These two queries work separately, but I can't figure out the way to combine them in one.

```
--displays all courses (its number, implementation, name) and teachers on the course
SELECT Course.subjectnumb, Course.coursenumb, Subject.subjectname, Course.participants, Teacher.firstname, Teacher.surname
FROM Course JOIN  Subject on Course.subjectnumb = Subject.subjectnumb  
JOIN Teacher on Course.teachernumb = Teacher.teachernumb  
ORDER BY Subject.subjectname ASC, Course.coursenumb ASC, Teacher.surname ASC

--display advisors names
SELECT teacher.firstname, teacher.surname 
FROM subject JOIN teacher ON teacher.teachernumb = subject.advisor 
ORDER BY teacher.surname ASC, teacher.firstname ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join twice on the same table. For example :

```
SELECT C.subjectnumb, C.coursenumb, 
       S.subjectname, C.participants, 
       TC.firstname as course_teacher_firstname, TC.surname as course_teacher_surname, 
       TS.firstname as subject_advisor_firstname, TS.surname as subject_advisor_surname, 
FROM Course C JOIN  Subject S on C.subjectnumb = S.subjectnumb  
JOIN Teacher TC on C.teachernumb = TC.teachernumb  
JOIN Teacher TS on S.advisor = TS.teachernumb 
ORDER BY S.subjectname ASC, C.coursenumb ASC, TC.surname ASC
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! Guess, the point of this task was exactly that.